# Found fatal error after firebase config

Tags: xcode, firebase, swift3

I am not able to sort out this exception. I have googled a lot about it but didn't find anything related to this!

*Note*: when I remove `FIRApp.configure()` from appDelegate then it works fine.

[image]

Any help will be really really appreciated!!!

Comment: I haven't touched firebase DB yet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found my answer while checking the `viewDidLoad()`

What I was doing wrong is that I was checking the FBSDKAccessToken before authentification (that was a silly one). So just removed the below code from the `viewDidLoad()`

```
//MARK: - VIEW DID LOAD
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()


    if (FBSDKAccessToken.current() != nil) {
        // User is already logged in, do work such as go to next view controller.
    }

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}
```